# Multiprocessing simple way to map a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like so:

```
models = {
    'Dummy1': DummyClassifier(strategy="constant", constant=1),
    'Dummy2': DummyClassifier(strategy="constant", constant=0),
    'Dummy3': DummyClassifier(strategy="constant", constant=0.5)
}
```

And I want to parallelise using `Pool.map` or a related function:

```
with Pool(threads) as p:
    result = p.map(partial(cross_validate, X=X, y=y), models.values())
```

This works but completely disregards the keys of the `models` dictionary. The `result` is simply a list. How can I get the result to be a dictionary with the same keys as the original?

```
results = {
    'Dummy1': 'Result1',
    'Dummy2': 'Result2',
    'Dummy3': 'Result3'
}
```

I have considered going based on the order of `models.items()`, however the documentation is mute on the ordering of the list `Pool.map` returns so I don't know if I can rely on the order being the same.

Comment: `Poo.map` is ordered so you can just zip `model.keys()` and `result` and make a new dictionary

Comment: You are passing `models.values()` to the map, so that's where your keys are being lost.

Comment: If you need to keep the keys and values, then pass them as 2-tuple values to the pool map, and then pass the results back in the same way, and then rebuild the dict from the tuples after the pool map completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
models = {
    'Dummy1': DummyClassifier(strategy="constant", constant=1),
    'Dummy2': DummyClassifier(strategy="constant", constant=0),
    'Dummy3': DummyClassifier(strategy="constant", constant=0.5)
}


pairs = (k, v) for k, v in models.items()

with Pool(threads) as p:
    result_pairs = p.map(partial(cross_validate, X=X, y=y), pairs)

results = {k: v for k, v in result_pairs}
```